# How to apply an operation along an axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, axis

I have an N-dimensional array, and I want to return another array of the same shape, where the values are progressively accumulated along a given axis. My attempt is below, but it throws an error because `put_along_axis` does not do exactly what I think it does. How to correctly write this?

```
def accumulate(data, axis):
    rez = np.zeros(data.shape)
    for i in range(1, data.shape[axis]):
        tmp1 = np.take(rez, i-1, axis=axis)
        tmp2 = np.take(rez, i, axis=axis)
        tmpsum = tmp1 + tmp2
        np.put_along_axis(rez, i, tmpsum, axis=axis)
    return rez
```

Comment: Not able to run on a 3D array for `data`. Can you add mcve?

Comment: @Divakar what is mcve?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: why do you need a minimal example. If I had an example code that worked, I would not need help. This is a minimal example, where everything works except of the line containing `put_along_axis`. The question is how to rewrite that line so that it works as intended

Comment: As I said `Not able to run on a 3D array for data.`.

Comment: What do you mean by `not able to run`? As I said, I am well aware that the code throws an error at the 2nd last line, that is exactly why I am asking the question

Comment: My bad, didn't read the error msg there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are just looking for `np.cumsum`:

```
data.cumsum(axis=axis)
```

will return just that.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thanks! I would still be interested on how to implement `cumsum` or another similar function, but this is not too important